# MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (2515, 406272) and data type float32

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, out-of-memory, ram

I am trying to make a finger knuckle recognition using CNN on Spyder on Anaconda. I have 2515 images that i am dealing with and it seems 8 GB  is not enough to do this. What can i do?
Should i get another stick of RAM or making this project on Kaggle/Colab will be a better approach?

```
arr = np.array(finger_dat)
arr = arr.reshape((2515, 406272))

arr = arr / 255

#############Making dataset####################

label = np.array(range(503))
label = np.repeat(label, 5)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(arr)
dataset['label'] = label

X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:406272]
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtf.fit(X, y)

dtf.score(X, y)
```

Comment: 2515 * 406272 * 32 is approximately 30.5 GB, so no, you don't have enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to process the data in batches.

Have a look in this doc. from sklearn:
[Strategies to scale computationally: bigger data](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your place I would try in this order:

colab,
change code to load batches
change code to use database to feed train
buy more ram but you are probably going to need > 40Gb.

Comment: Thanks, i was just trying it out on colab. Colab shows a new error with me resizing loop that i was not getting on jupyter. Any change you can help me with that?

Comment: **IndexError: list index out of range**